# Add key to registry if not exist

Tags: c#, registry

I try to add a key to the registry if not exist.
While I debug everything is fine. Code should work. But I can't find key in registry editor. Do you have any idea?

```
public void ConfigureWindowsRegistry()
{
    var reg = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Office\\Outlook\\FormRegions\\tesssst", true);
    if (reg == null)
    {
        reg = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Office\\Outlook\\FormRegions\\tesssst");
    }

    if (reg.GetValue("someKey") == null)
    {
            reg.SetValue("someKey", "someValue");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are using a 64bit OS some registry keys are redirected by WOW64. More information on this topic is available on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232(v=vs.85).aspx) , you should look under Wow6432Node and you will find your entry. If you execute that code the first time it will create, on a 64 bit machine (I tried it locally), this entry:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node \Microsoft\Office\Outlook\FormRegions\tesssst

if you want to access your 64 bit section of the registry you should do:

```
public void ConfigureWindowsRegistry()
{
    RegistryKey localMachine = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64); //here you specify where exactly you want your entry

   var reg = localMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Office\\Outlook\\FormRegions\\tesssst",true);
   if (reg == null)
   {
       reg = localMachine.CreateSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Office\\Outlook\\FormRegions\\tesssst");
   }

   if (reg.GetValue("someKey") == null)
   {
       reg.SetValue("someKey", "someValue");
   }
}
```

Executing the code above will put the registry key in the correct section you are targeting.

hope it helps.